# Redirect to final step of checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have an option where the client will pay an order after internal validation.

The client places the order with a custom payment method and then I restore the order for the client to pay.

What I'm trying to achieve is in this cases redirect the client to the final step of payment. here is the code.

```
$this->quoteRepository->save($new_quote);
$this->checkoutSession->replaceQuote($new_quote);
$this->checkoutSession->setQuoteId($new_quote->getid()); 
$this->cart->save();

$cartUrl        = $this->url->getUrl('checkout/#payment/');
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();                    
$resultRedirect->setUrl($cartUrl);
return $resultRedirect;
```

This will redirect to the payment step but then redirects me to a noroute page, can anybody help?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so, after some hours of digging up it all comes down to one line of code.

```
$this->_redirect('checkout', ['_fragment' => 'payment']);
```